# How to get type parameter values using java reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

```
interface Foo<T> { ... }
class Bar implements Foo<Baz> { ... }
```

I've got a `Bar` object. How to get the value of `T` for it (`Baz`)?

So far, I only managed to get the interface and `T`, but I can't see a way to get its value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Type type = bar.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0];

if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    Type actualType = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    System.out.println(actualType);
}
```

Of course, in the general case, you should iterate over the array, rather than assuming it has excatly one element (`[0]`). With the above example, you can cast `actualType` to `java.lang.Class`. In other cases it may be different (see comment by meriton)

Comment: Note that in general, `actualType` is not necessarily a plain `java.lang.Class` - it could also be a `GenericArrayType`, a `ParametrizedType`, or a `TypeVariable`.

Comment: True. I meant that in his case it's `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Guava on the classpath, this is a bit more robust as you specify the interface/superclass by type rather than index.

```
TypeToken<?> baz = TypeToken.of(Bar.class).resolveType(Foo.class.getTypeParameters()[0]);
System.out.println(baz.getRawType()); // class Baz
```