# Print value of parametized type in java

Tags: java, generics

Please bear new in java.

I'm trying to understand generics it was smooth until I came to this:

```java
Pair<Integer, GenericBox<String>> p2 = new OrderedPair<>(1, new GenericBox<>("Parametized Type");
p2.print();
```

Print method:

```java
public void print() {
    System.out.println(this.key + ", " + this.value);
}
```

It works fine except when I used parametized type argument.

Sample output:

```
1, GenericBox@41171d93
```

Expected output:

```
1, Parametized Type
```

Tried this: [How to get type parameter values using java reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609799/how-to-get-type-parameter-values-using-java-reflection) but it only gives me K which is a parameter in OrderedPair''

This is my first question here, if there are things that I miss or things that are unclear, feedbacks are very much appreciated.

Comment: you need to override the toString of your GenericBox class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with generics. With

```
this.value
```

you're presumably referring to the `GenericBox` object you passed to the `OrderedPair` constructor. This class (`GenericBox`) must not have a declared `toString()` method. It therefore inherits and uses `Object#toString()`.

It's up to the developer to write their own `toString()` implementation and return any `String` value they deem appropriate. [Here's what the official tutorials have to say.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)